# Automate Microsoft teams using ui automation c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, ui-automation, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft's inspect tool to view Uiobject properties like name, automationid.but none of the uiobjects are visible in the inspect tool.

Is there any way to automate teams app?

Comment: What do you need to do with the app? If you're using C# to develop something in Teams, it might be better to investigate using Microsoft's Graph API to manage Teams.

Comment: Here's the [link to the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: I want to do chat, voice, video calls. To use graph API, office 365 required I think. I don't have office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Teams App is simply a Window with a browser in it. This most likely is why you don’t see anything. No windows forms, no WPF or any MS tech it’s Chromium based.

As you use the word Automation I’m going to guess you are looking for a way to create code which automates the Teams App, like you do in for example office or you could do with MS Communicator. You could code to start a call and the UI would do it.  Simple answer here is you cannot And it’s intentional so you probably never will. MS want you to build web based add ins like the successful web add ins for office 365 :-).

[i had a similar question and here is my own answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61691936/678412)